# Can one menu inside my PHP site run as Angular application

Tags: php, angular

Actually I want integrate Angular functionality inside PHP Application.

PHP Application running currently on live ( having separate database and API calls written in Java)

Angular Application which I am developing currently (ng7) have it's own database and API calls written in Java.

Is it possible to run both apps under PHP site ( domain will not change)

If yes then how can I integrate Angular app inside PHP site for e.g. PHP site will have a menu i.e. when user clicks on that menu then page loaded will be an Angular and all functionality inside that menu will be of Angular calling it's own Java API's

Do we need to handle session in this case if two apps are running separately, and how to pass control from PHP site to Angular and vice versa

Comment: Since Angular is client side (js), you can use what ever back end you want. Angular just does API calls and doesn't care about the under laying technology. You can have an Angular app that calls Java, PHP, Python or what ever language you want within the same app. If you want to use both Java and PHP and share sessions between them (you need to implement something custom for that), I would seriously consider rethinking the architecture to use one or the other. That question would probably be a bit broad as well.

Comment: Hi Magnus, if we think the way in which I want then do I need to keep code on same server or separate server ( aws ec2 )  i.e. because client also want to white label it afterwards for other tenants. So what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run both of the application on the same domain but you will require any folder pattern to keep the Angular App bundle.

E.g. you have a domain http://example.com then you can write an .htaccess rule to forward the conditional request to Angular and others to PHP.

Then for that PHP URL, you need to provide the href='' link in the Angular rather than the routerlink otherwise Angular will find that module in the Angular route.

You also need to take care about the `baseUrl` of your application.

Sample `.htaccess` rule looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|flv|mpeg|mpg|mp4)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [NC,L]
```

Keep it in same directory where you are putting your Angular code.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks for reply, but angular application has functionality of login and registration also. Wherever user is registered it goes in both database ( PHP + Angular ). So if user is logged in PHP Application then same he should be logged into angular app also and vice-versa, So in this case how to manage the session between both apps ?

Comment: PHP stores the session on the server and understands it by the browser cookie. so if you are using same domain for API calls on Angular so that session will also be available in that request so you can send the data by reading that. then on the Angular you need to keep the login session in the local storage and use interceptor method to authenticate the each request on server by adding `Authentication` header